# How to update iframe in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, iframe

I have an Iframe

```
<iframe v-show="this.$store.getters['rackStore/getIframe'].show === 'iframe'" ref="iframe_3d" :src="this.$store.getters['rackStore/getIframe'].ref" id="iframe_3d" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 1px solid #00f; "></iframe>
```

And it displays the data perfectly.

Src I take from Vuex

Then I want to change the src value:

```
let iframe_param = this.$store.getters['rackStore/getIframe'];
this.$store.commit('rackStore/setIframe', { ...iframe_param, show: 'iframe', ref: model.ref } );
```

And I mean in the console that the src value of the iframe is changing!
But the iframe itself is not updated in the browser for some reason.

I tried to force update it: this.$ForceUpdate ();
This does not work.

I've tried changing the src in the usual way without Vue, this also doesn't work:

```
    <iframe v-show="this.$store.getters['rackStore/getIframe'].show === 'iframe'" ref="iframe_3d"
    src="" id="iframe_3d" 
    allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 1px solid #00f; ">
</iframe>

  var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_3d');
  iframe.src = model.ref;
```

src changes but no data refresh occurs, the previous site is still open in the iframe

What to do?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try update the element using `key` attribute:

```
<template>
<!-- ... -->
<iframe v-show="this.$store.getters['rackStore/getIframe'].show === 'iframe'" ref="iframe_3d" :src="this.$store.getters['rackStore/getIframe'].ref" id="iframe_3d" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: 1px solid #00f; " :key="iframeUpdate"></iframe>
<!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
   // ...
   data() {
        return {
            iframeUpdate: false
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

When your value in Vuex changes, simultaneously change `iframeUpdate` variable value like this:

```
this.iframeUpdate = !this.iframeUpdate;
```